# Servicemix and bundle Name/ Symbolic Name

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-servicemix

I got a bug or maybe I forgot a thing but servicemix does not want to put the correct bundle name / symbolic name :

```
Command list : 
[ 221] [Active ] [] [] [   60] mvn:org.emp.idewe.ipsi/esb-precube/1.2.2-SNAPSHOT

Instead of : 
[ 221] [Active ] [] [] [   60] Idewe:Esb-PreCube (1.2.2-SNAPSHOT)

and command list -s : 
[ 221] [Active ] [] [] [   60] no symbolic name
```

My Manifest.mf :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: ...
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Name: Idewe:Esb-PreCube
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Bundle-Vendor: ...
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_29
Bundle-Version: 1.2.2.SNAPSHOT
Bnd-LastModified: 1344950093005
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: ...
Import-Package: ...
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.emp.idewe.ipsi.esb-precube
```

and my feature.xml :

```
<feature name="Esb-PreCube.1.2.2-SNAPSHOT" version="1.2.2-SNAPSHOT">
  <feature>camel-spring</feature>
  <bundle>mvn:org.emp.idewe.ipsi/esb-precube/1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
</feature>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps your manifest is not at the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like your bundle isn't configured correctly since the bundle symbolic name isn't resolved. If this is corrected Karaf/Servicemix will deploy it right away with the right name.